# How to use adaboost with different base estimator in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, adaboost, ensemble-learning

I want to use adaboost with several base estimators for regression in scikit-learning, but I don't find any class that can do it. Is there any way to do this things except changing source code?

Answer (score 4):

You can read this page on sklearn: [adaboost](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#adaboost).
I personally like stacking XGboost,GBM, RandomForest and ExtraTree as base models and stacking them to get better auc score.

Comment: If you want to stack or blend multiple base estimators, you can check out this module on github: [stacked generalization](https://github.com/andreashsieh/stacked_generalization). This module was developed by dustinstansbury and I made a patch for it to make the code working better.

Comment: I am using adaboost for regression, so this module may not help me

Comment: @AndreasHsieh: how do you stack different algorithms?

Answer (score 2):

I may not understand your question, but if all you want to do is have an Adaboost regressor with a base estimator of your choosing, you can just create the base model and feed it in as the `base_estimator` parameter of `AdaboostRegressor()`.

A simple example using adaboost with an support vector machine regressor is:

```
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostRegressor

my_base_model= SVR()
my_ensemble = AdaBoostRegressor(base_estimator=my_base_model)
```

You would want to put parameters into each these calls to customize the base estimator and the ensemble, but the basic skeleton is as above.